# tmap title on wrong graphic

Tags: r, r-markdown, tmap

I wonder if this is a bug in tmap while using tmap_mode("view"). I want a title to appear on the last graphic but instead the title is put on the third graphic. The tmap_("plot") option place the title on the correct graphic. See code below:

````
---
title: "Embedding tmap in RMarkdown"
output: html_document
---


```{r}
library(tmap)
tmap_options(check.and.fix = TRUE)
```

```{r,echo=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width=9.5,fig.align='center',warning = FALSE, message = FALSE,comment="",echo = TRUE) 

```

# Maps made in plot mode

```{r}
tmap_mode("plot")
data(World)
tm_shape(World) +
  tm_polygons("HPI") 
```

```{r}
tm_shape(World) +
  tm_polygons("HPI") + tm_layout(main.title = "Plot Mode")
```

# Maps made in view mode

```{r}
tmap_mode("view")
data(World)
tm_shape(World) +
  tm_polygons("HPI", id = "iso_a3", popup.vars = TRUE)
```

```{r}
tm_shape(World) + tm_polygons() +
  tm_layout(title = "View Mode")
#I want title on this graphic but instead the title pops up on the graphic above this one.
```
````